# Merge of [quickcontact] and [quickcontactbadge] tags

Tags: feature-request, retag-request, synonym-request

I think that the [quickcontact](/questions/tagged/quickcontact) and [quickcontactbadge](/questions/tagged/quickcontactbadge) tags could be merged, or one could be set as a synonym for the other.

I have not enough reputation to suggest such a modification. Do you think this is acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel these tags should be removed altogether.  It's not because there are so few of them, but because it's about a specific class in the framework, which is generally *too* specific for a tag.

That said, I'm sure all of the questions are searchable on variations of "quickcontact" ("quick" and "contact").

And on a very personal nature, I just hate seeing [quickcontactbadge](/questions/tagged/quickcontactbadge), it just runs on and looks like jibberish (although changing it to [quick-contact-badge](/questions/tagged/quick-contact-badge) would be preferable, I don't know if it would be appropriate).

Comment: I agree on the readability of quick-contact-badge.